# Enum default value to skip existing records rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, enums

I have a huge number of records on DB, and want to **add a new column**. However, **I don't want to set default values to old existing records**, only to the new.

When I set default on migration (as shown below), all old existing will receive default.

```
add_column :records, :status, :integer, default: 0
```

Problem is, if I only add default to enum, like so:

```
enum status: {
    to_review: 0,
    pending: 1,
    processed: 2
  }, _default: :to_review
```

I get this error

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `all?' for :to_review:Symbol)
```

How can I add a new column, set default value and still keep old records as *null*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the documentation here it seems you are on a right track

https://api.rubyonrails.org/v6.1.4/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html

```
enum status: { to_review: 0, pending: 1, processed: 2}, _default: :to_review
```

**Note:** The support for _default has been added in **rails 6.1** - [pull request](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/39820)

Please check if you're using the supported version

Comment: You're right! I'll check your link carefully. Unfortunately we're using 6.01. Another alternative would be using before_save, but that would be an extra callback.

Comment: Well, you can always set the default value at the database level in the migration.